# Is there a way to do bulk actions in ISPCofig?

Tags: debian, bulk, ispconfig

I am using IPSConfig 3.0.5.4p9, on Debian Jessie. 
Is it possible to do bulk actions in ISPConfig WebPanel? 
By actions, I mean:

- Add New Sites Domains
- Modify multile Site Domains to the same parameter
- Add multiple catch-all emails
- Add multiple Email Domains

If it is not possible to do so from within ISPConfig itself, is it possible to do so programmatically?